# Efficient Way to Sync Prod and Staging Databases (Postgres)

Tags: database, postgresql, data-synchronization

I have a production and staging environments for my application. I am using Postgres (RDS instance) and Django. I want to sync my staging postgres database with production database.

Actually I want to know the best and efficient practices to have same data on both databases (prod and staging). Is there any syncing or replication process that resolve my issue? I don't want to spend my time daily on taking dump from one database and restore in another. I would be very happy if there is something real time replication of data or scheduled replication after 6 or 8 hours.
Kindly share your thought on this.

Comment: [Logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

Comment: PostgreSQL has any number of ways to do replication, but typically one does **not** sync the **data** on staging and production databases! You **do** sync schema changes. Typically this is done with [schema migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) so the changes made in development can be replicated in production. adjusting production data to the new schema changes.

Comment: I just want my data duplicated on both databases. All new data should be populated from production database to staging db. But I like it to be efficient.